# not able to install javaws

Tags: java, applet, openjdk

I need to use java web start to run TopCoders `ContestAppletProd.jnlp`. 
When I try to run the  the arena I get Java not found error.

[image]

Upon selecting the option "using Java Web Start" the jnlp file opens up in firefox showing a download dialog which keeps on recurring.

[image]

The commands java and javac pretty much work on my system but javaws shows some package is required which on installation command says its already installed.

[image]

Has anybody come across this problem? any suggestions to solve are appreciated.

Comment: How did you install java? And what version did you install?

Comment: What about `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javaws` (replace the version(6/7) and architecture(amd64/x86) by your own if they do not match)

Comment: with openjdk-7-jre and openjdk-7-jdk installed, javaws is not present, only java compilers and such.

Answer (score 6):

Installed java-8-openjdk-amd64:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

And I had the same problem.

Install oracle-java solution for me:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

javaws -version
Java(TM) Web Start 11.45.2.14-fcs
...
```

Select the desired platform for Java, you can:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

The oracle's package worked for me also.

```
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java). 
Selection    Path  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ sudo find / -name "javaws"
/usr/bin/javaws
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/javaws
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/javaws
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/javaws
/etc/alternatives/javaws
```

/usr/bin/javaws -> (i.e. points-to)   /etc/alternatives/javaws*

I pointed jnlp to /usr/bin/javaws in Firefox's settings.

There was no javaws before the oracle installer:

```
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ sudo find / -name "*javaws*"
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/icedtea-netx-common:icedtea-netx-javaws.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/javaws.png
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/javaws
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-universe/64x64/icedtea-netx-common_javaws.png
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$ 
milen@milen-Lenovo-B50-80:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install `icedtea` to add web start, instead of switching to Oracle.

On Debian 10: `apt install icedtea-netx`