# Installing Java Web Start: Java 12

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

### Solution found and implemented. See below original post.

My JVM installation apparently does not contain javaws.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep ^java
java                           manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/java
javac                          manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/javac
javadoc                        manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/javadoc
javap                          manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/javap
```

I have used both the PPA and a direct install from Oracle [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html) with this [documentation](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

I need `javaws` to launch a `jnlp` file. The app apparently needs the Oracle distribution and not OpenJDK.

I tried v11 and v8 but PPA appears to be unavailable due to new licensing.

This is not a duplicate of [not able to install javaws](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293117/not-able-to-install-javaws) because webupd8team's PPA and oracle-java8-installer doesn't exist anymore due to new licensing:

`javaws` does not appear to be in the main v12 distribution as per the directory structure.

[image: Picture of tarball file.]

---

SOLUTION: Do not use ppa, Register for Oracle Network, download JDK8, install manually. javaws does not exist for v11+

Download:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Install JVM manually using: 
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Not a duplicate due to new oracle licensing which has removed oracle-java8-installer

Comment: I tried both methods. When I download the v12 tarball file and inspect it javaws isn't in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Java Web Start is no longer included since Java 11 SE. Excerpt from [Java Client Road Map (Update 2018-03-05)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf):

> Java Web Start has become a migration path for developers as browser
>   vendors continued to restrict plugin support over the past several
>   years.
>
> Since it is predominantly a desktop technology,Web Start has some
>   limitations. In particular, it requires a standalone JRE to be
>   installed and maintained on the user’s desktop.
>
> However, over the past decade,vendors of the most popular desktop
>   operating systems have emphatically pushed for applications on their
>   platforms to be delivered bundled with integrated, sandboxed runtimes.
>   Increasingly they require desktop applications to be distributed
>   through their own private "app stores".
>
> The notion of an application being distributed separately from a
>   standalone JRE is,therefore,quickly fading.
>
> Consequently:
>
> - Oracle will extend support for Web Start in Java SE 8 from March, 2019, through at least March 2025.
> - Oracle products that have dependencies on Web Start will remain on Java SE 8 and continue with the support timelines as indicated by
>     those products.
> - **Oracle will not include Java Web Start in Java SE 11(18.9LTS)and later.**
> - Oracle will begin encouraging application developers and users to transition away from Java Web Start and encourage non-commercial
>     consumers to remove any unused or non-supported Oracle JRE
>     installations from their desktops.
> - Developers who deploy desktop applications to individual consumers (eg, games, personal banking, or other B2C applications) will need to
>     transition to other deployment technologies such as the jlink and/or
>     third party packaging and deployment solutions before the end of 2020.
> - Application developers who target applications for internal data processing, business, commercial, or production purposes, will either
>     need to seek commercial license with Oracle, or transition to other
>     deployment technologies by January 2019.

Therefore, if you really need Java Web Start you need to switch to Java 8.