# How to make IcedTea use OpenJDK instead of (no longer installed) Oracle Java?

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, oracle, icedtea

I had some issues with an .jnlp file using OpenJDK so I installed Oracle Java.
It didn't work either, so I uninstalled it (the config folder is still there though).

Now, if I want to open something with IcedTea, it tries to use Oracle Java, although no longer installed (if I interpret the terminal output correctly).

```bash
$ javaws FILENAME.jnlp

selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle

thread 'main' panicked at 'Error spawning JVM process, java executable: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle], arguments: [["-splash:/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws_splash.png", "-Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws.jar:/usr/share/java/js.jar:/usr/share/java/tagsoup.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:", "-classpath", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:", "-Dicedtea-web.bin.name=javaws", "-Dicedtea-web.bin.location=/usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/javaws", "net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot", "FILENAME.jnlp"]]', src/os_access.rs:36:19
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

I tried reinstalling OpenJDK and IcedTea.

```bash
$ java - version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.10.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.10.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have read along another question [(*How to set default Java version?*)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version) question and tried `update-alternatives --config java;` but it says there is only one java version and nothing to choose.

I assume I have to change something in the config files of IcedTea?

[edit] I also cannot access `$itweb-settings`, it comes up with the same error as in the first box. I'm about to install oracle java, then hopefully change iced tea's configuration and then uninstall it again.

```bash
$ sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep ^java

java                auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
javaws              manual   /usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/javaws
```

Comment: Have you tried to update alternatives for javaws? Also, AFAIK [javaws has been deprecated since JDk11](https://askubuntu.com/a/1137784/816190).

Comment: You are right, there were some "leftovers" from Oracle java (javap, javac javadoc). I updated these and now those entrances are gone, but of course the iced tea entrance was correct all along.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by above comment.